# Fetching FIRST lowest value in table and the date on which it occurs, for every distinct user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the first lowest value in a table, and the date on which it occurs, for every DISTINCT user in a table.

This is the table schema and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE diet_watch (
  entry_date date NOT NULL,
  user_id    int default 1,
  weight     double precision NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-01', 1, 128.2);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-02', 1, 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-03', 1, 122.3);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-04', 1, 303.7);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-05', 1, 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-01', 2, 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-06', 2, 128.0);
```

The SQL I came up with is here in [this snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7aa4e/13)

I have since been informed that it is incorrect, perhaps someone can explain what the problem with my SQL is ?

Note: I would prefer ANSI SQL if possible, but I am using PostgreSQL, so if I have to use a specific flavour of SQL, it has to work on PG.

Comment: I can't get to SQL FIddle right now. Can you post your query?

Comment: @RedFilter - is SQL Fiddle not working for you? What's going on?

Comment: @JakeFeasel It's good now - I think the server was just getting hit hard, page took a couple of minutes to render. But it was OK after that.

Comment: @JakeFeasel it's hanging again...

Comment: @RedFilter wow - yeah there was certainly something going on with it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>*Note: Not sure if Window functions are ANSI SQL*</del>

WINDOW Functions are a part of the  SQL:2003 specification: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_%28SQL%29#Window_function (Thx
@a_horse_with_no_name)

Try this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7aa4e/22

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
    (
     SELECT a.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY weight) AS Position
       FROM diet_watch a

    ) a
    WHERE a.Position = 1
```

Comment: Yes, window functions **are** ANSI SQL (since 2003).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Was trying to get an online reference to post here. If you one handy can you pls post it?

Comment: @Chandu: Cool!. Nice and succinct code!. +1. BTW, what was wrong with my original SQL?

Answer (score 1):

First, your query is needlessly complicated.  You can just put the group by in the subquery and eliminate the outer query.

The windows function, mentioned by @Chandu, is a very good solution.  It is ANSI SQL and postgres supports it.  However, not all databases do.  An alternative is:

```
select dw.*
from diet_watch dw join
     (select user_id, min(entry_date) as mindate
      from diet_watch dw
      group by user_id
     ) dwmin
     on dw.user_id = dwmin.user_id and dw.entry_date = dwmin.mindate
```

The reason your original query doesn't work is because the minimum entry_date may not have the minimum weight.  Your query retrieves the minimum of each field independently.  This version finds the minimum date, then joins that back to the original table to get the weight (and other information) on that day.

Comment: Actually nearly all DBMS support windowing functions. There are only very few that don't (notably MySQL and SQLite)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the first time each user achieved their minimum weight, I think this works. I see in the test data, user 1 achieves their minimum of 121 twice, and you want the first date? To my knowledge this should work on every SQL engine.

```
SELECT min(dw.entry_date), dw.user_id, dw.weight FROM diet_watch dw,
    (SELECT min(weight) AS "weight", user_id FROM diet_watch GROUP BY user_id) mins
WHERE dw.user_id = mins.user_id AND dw.weight = mins.weight
GROUP BY dw.user_id, dw.weight
```

The inner select finds each user's minimum weight. Another min is necessary on the date, because otherwise you wouldn't be specifically selecting the first time that minimum weight was achieved for that user.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7aa4e/51/0